# Envoy on local machine with Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, envoyproxy

Im [learning Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/on-your-laptop) while trying to get a local setup with Laravel. The aim is to when navigate to `/service/1`, I should see a Laravel page. I'd expect to see a Laravel page error as there is not a page called `/service/1` but at least I know the route is correct.

**Laravel Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
# to the directory /var/www/api/
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/api/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/api

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www/api

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/api

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

My tree structure:

```
foo
 |_ api (laravel)
 |_ envoy
```

Envoy's root directory is inside the folder `envoy` along with the examples that I've cloned.

Inside `/evoy/examples/front-proxy/`:

- **docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  front-envoy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-frontenvoy
    volumes:
      - ./front-envoy.yaml:/etc/front-envoy.yaml
    networks:
      - envoymesh
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "8001"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8001:8001"

  laravel:
    build:
      context: ../../../api/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: laravel_api
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: laravel_api
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/api
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/api
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      envoymesh:
        aliases:
          - laravel
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=1
    expose:
      - "80"

  service2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-service
    volumes:
      - ./service-envoy.yaml:/etc/service-envoy.yaml
    networks:
      envoymesh:
        aliases:
          - service2
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=2
    expose:
      - "80"

networks:
  envoymesh: {}
```

- **front-envoy.yaml:**

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/1"
                route:
                  cluster: laravel
              - match:
                  prefix: "/service/2"
                route:
                  cluster: service2
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            typed_config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: laravel
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: laravel
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 80
  - name: service1
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service1
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: service1
                port_value: 80
  - name: service2
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service2
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: service2
                port_value: 80
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

I've changed the cluster (laravel) to match [this tutorial](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/10/27/envoy-basics/) but when I navigate to `localhost:8000/service/1`, I get:

> upstream request timeout

Navigating to `localhost:8000/service/2` is ok.

Larevel's `.env` has the variable `APP_PORT=8000`.

To recap, I'm learning Envoy as I go along. When I go to `localhost:8000/service/1` I expect to get a Laravel page missing error or an error from Laravel itself as there is no such path, as yet, `/service/1`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the envoy configuration you've got the laravel cluster with a type of `STRICT_DNS`, but it has an address of `127.0.0.1`. Inside the docker-compose network this won't work.

You can simply put `laravel` as the address instead, which will be resolved to the containers address within the compose network.

Here's an excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#embedded-dns-server) to further explain:

> Docker daemon runs an embedded DNS server which provides DNS resolution among containers connected to the same user-defined network, so that these containers can resolve container names to IP addresses.